# discord.py Using custom checks for blacklist

Tags: python, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do**: I had some people abuse my bot's commands, so I wanted to put a stop to this. Therefore, after reviewing multiple sources of code, I got as far as inserting member ids into a `.txt` document.

**My problem**: My 'custom check' has been having errors. All the custom check examples that I had found were in `cogs` or were not related to what I was trying to do, therefore I haven't gotten mine to work as expected yet. Note that I am not using cogs, either.

**Code**:

```py
def blacklist(ctx): # this is the def used for the check, it reads the .txt file for user
    file = open("blacklist.txt", "r")
    members_banned = file.readlines()
    if str(ctx.author.id) not in members_banned:
        return ctx.author.id not in members_banned

@client.command() # this command is used for adding people to the blacklist. This is most likely not the problem..
@commands.is_owner()
async def blacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    file = open("blacklist.txt", "r")
    anything = False
    while anything == False:
        content = file.read()
        things = content.split("\n")
        for line in things:
            if str(line) == str(member.id):
                await ctx.send(f"{member.name} is already in blacklist, please remove manually!")
                anything = True
            else:
                pass
        if anything == False:
            thing = open("blacklist.txt", "a")
            thing.write(f"\n{member.id}")
            thing.close()
            anything = True
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}: {member.name} has been blacklisted, hopefully")
        file.close()
        break

@client.command()
@commands.check(blacklist) # This is the code I used to test the custom check for the blacklist
async def bltest(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Cool, you're not blacklisted")
```

**Errors**: (via this code)

```
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: blacklist() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

The above error doesn't make any sense to me.

**Others**:

The .txt file

[image: My text file with the ids]

Other code I have looked at:

- [Code found after looking through previous questions asked in the discord.py server](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/757115231377031169/811813788764340224/unknown.png)
- [Code found while trying to look for check examples, this is in a cog](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/757115231377031169/811878947213803540/unknown.png?width=482&height=463)
- [The discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your functions have the same name. The command is named `blacklist` with the `ctx` and `member` parameter, while the function's name is `blacklist` with just `ctx` as a parameter. This means if the wrong one is chosen, you're calling a function that expects 2 arguments & only giving it 1.

Give the first function (the one that reads the file) a different name, like "check_blacklist" or "blacklisted" or whatever suits you best.

Answer (score -2):

As it says in the error in the first line of code add member as an argument to the function blacklist. You need it because in this function you are dealing with member of the discord server.